# Convert rows from a NoSQL schema to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot, nosql

I understand how to use PIVOT to rotate rows into columns but I have a unique scenario where rows also have to be grouped. The source data is from a NoSQL database schema (un-relational). Here is an example of the source data:

```
ID case_id field_id sequence_number textvalue
1  12897     25            100        AAAAA
2  12897     50            100        BBBBB
3  12897     75            100        CCCCC
4  13587     25            200        DDDDD
5  13587     50            200        EEEEE
6  13587     75            200        FFFFF
7  13587    100            200        GGGGG
```

The result I need is:

```
case_id  value_field_id_25  value_field_id_50  value_field_id_75  value_field_id_100
12897         AAAAA               BBBBB              CCCCC
13587         DDDDD               EEEEE              FFFFF              GGGGG
```

So, what I need is a row of related records grouped by sequence_number. The number of rows with the same sequence_number is dynamic (it varies).

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the number of columns always going to be 4 at the most?

Comment: No. It will vary.

Comment: Then take a look at John's dynamic pivot. It is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select ',' + QuoteName('value_field_id_'+cast(field_id as varchar(25))) 
                                    From (Select Distinct Top 100 Percent field_id 
                                           From YourTable 
                                           Order by 1) A 
                                     For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [case_id],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select sequence_number  
              ,case_id
              ,ColName = ''value_field_id_''+cast(field_id as varchar(25))
              ,Value   = textvalue
         From YourTable A
     ) A
 Pivot (max([Value]) For [ColName] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Why the top 100 percent? And ordering by ordinal position is not a good habit. You should move that order by to the outer query to ensure row order. But still well deserving of a +1. :D

Comment: @SeanLange Just to keep the proper order otherwise 100 becomes first column

Comment: But the order by is on a subquery which means you still can't ensure the order of the outer query results. It will most likely work on this small set but it is possible the order will not always be the same.

Comment: @SeanLange Now, if I had a distinct or where, in that top query, the order would not be gtd.

Comment: @SeanLange I've yet to witness an issue with table variables, or ordered sub-queries

Comment: Me neither...yet. :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks. I get the logic now.

Comment: @Nigel Happy to help  :)